# Flutter GNav disappears when using Navigator.pushNamed()

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, navbar

I implemented an app that uses GNav from google_nav_bar.dart. Most things work fine and I really like it, i can manually switch pages by clicking on the tab icons of the navbar. But when I am trying to change the page in the code (e.g. Buttonpress or after the User did a certain action) with Navigator.pushNamed the navbar disappears. I know that this is normal bcs why should the navbar stay, but I have no idea how to manage this. There are not that many examples on the internet. Would be pretty nice if someone could help me!
Explanation of the app: the User scans a barcode of a book, and after the scan he gets redirected to the app page, where the user can find reviews to that book. And i want the navbar on that reviews page as well.
Here the simplified code where the navigation happens, the different screens just return a Scaffold, they are not implemented yet:

```
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static final List<Widget> _pages = <Widget>[
    const ScannerScreen(),
    const AllReviewsScreen(),

  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('ReviewApp'),
          ),
          body: _pages.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
          bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 0),
              child: GNav(
                gap: 8,
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                color: Colors.white,
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                tabBackgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                tabs: const [
                  GButton(
                    icon: Icons.qr_code_scanner,
                    text: 'Scanner',
                  ),
                  GButton(
                    icon: Icons.reviews,
                    text: 'Alle Reviews',
                  ),
            
                ],
                selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
                onTabChange: (index) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedIndex = index;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          switch (settings.name) {
            case '/scanner':
              return FadeRoute(const ScannerScreen());
            case '/all_reviews':
              return FadeRoute(const AllReviewsScreen());

            default:
              return null;
          }
        });
  }
}
```

I tried to use a tabController, but GoogleNavBar has no controller, so I think it handles this another way, but I hardly found stuff on the internet, in every example they only switch screen using the navbar. Of course i could just implement the navbar on every screen, but there must be an easier way

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious behavior because when you call Navigator. push it immediately pushes the UI to a new screen where your bottomAppBar is not available.

Here is an article about what you want:
[Multiple Navigators with BottomNavigationBar](https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-case-study-multiple-navigators-with-bottomnavigationbar-90eb6caa6dbf)